# Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date

Tags: sql-server

I had a select statement which converted my date columns to varchar and then to int which worked in SSMS and gave my result that i wanted to see. In SSIS it started throwing errors so I decided to use table variables in my select statement and send the data to there and then use that data to insert it in my main table using SSIS data flow.

My select statement is giving the error:

```
Msg 206, Level 16, State 2, Line 71
Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date
```

My Select statement is:

```
DECLARE @Order TABLE (
    [OrderCode] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [PersonCode] [BIGINT] NOT NULL,
    [OrderDateTimeBase] [INT] NULL,
    [OrderlineCreateDate] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [OrderlineDateTimeBase] [INT] NULL,
    [OrderlineDateBase] [DATE] NULL,
    [BackOrderPromiseDate] [INT] NULL,
    [CancelDate] [INT] NULL,
    [DespatchedDate] [INT] NULL,
    [ReturnDate] [INT] NULL,
    [ExchangeDate] [INT] NULL
);

INSERT INTO @Order
SELECT
      CAST(LEFT(o.[personCode]
    , CHARINDEX('~', o.[personCode]) - 1) AS BIGINT) AS 'PersonCode'
    , CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), o.[OrderDatetimeBase], 112)) AS 'OrderDateTimeBase'
    , CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), ol.[OrderlineCreateDate], 112)) AS 'OrderlineCreateDate'
    , CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), ol.[OrderlinedatetimeBase], 112)) AS 'OrderlinedatetimeBase'
    , CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), ol.[OrderlineDateBase], 112)) AS 'OrderlineDateBase'
    , CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), ol.[BackOrderPromiseDate], 112)) AS 'BackOrderPromiseDate'
    , CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), ol.[CancelDate], 112)) AS 'CancelDate'
    , CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), ol.[DespatchedDate], 112)) AS 'DespatchedDate'
    , CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), ol.[ReturnDate], 112)) AS 'ReturnDate'
    , CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), ol.[ExchangeDate], 112)) AS 'ExchangeDate'
FROM dbo.A ol
INNER JOIN dbo.B o ON o.orderID = ol.orderID;

SELECT * FROM @Order
```

Comment: Is this SQL Server? Could you tag your question with that?

Comment: is it not sql? but ok, sorry about that

Comment: @Faiz, SQL is a query language, not a product. MS SQL Server is one of many products that support the SQL language.

Comment: You're converting the value into an `INT` while trying to `INSERT` it into a `DATE` column (`OrderlineDateBase`).

Comment: ahh silly error, and i thought my code was not right. i ll check it all for next time before I waste other peoples time due to my fault. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some of your fields (like *OrderlineCreateDate*) are not of the `date` but `int` type. But `CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), field, 112)` expects *field* to be a `date`, so there is a data type conflict.

If those fields are really intended to be of the type `int` one could wonder why you would convert those to `varchar` and then back to `int` again.

And then you insert them into a table that expects them to a be a `date`.

Answer (score 2):

The substance of your question has been addressed, but I will also add that I ran into this error because I was starting with a date column containing only a NULL.

When I tried to insert that column's data later, I guess the column expecting an actual date value interpreted the NULL as int (or otherwise got confused). I'm not sure the NULL would cause this error every time, but it is something to check for if you're seeing this error.

Comment: and this happened even if date column is nullable?

Comment: Thanks, that's a great question. I don't recall whether the error happened when the date column was nullable, but I will test it out if I can dig up the original query I had trouble with.